# Moment find difference between two date object

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have two dates in my project which are

```
let a="30-03-1999"
let b="30-03-2022"
```

Now i need to find the difference between these two dates, so first i am converting them to moment object by

```
let birthdate = moment(a, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
let licenseDate = moment(b, 'DD-MM-YYYY')

//console.log(birthdate,licenseDate) gives me moment object 

Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "30-03-1950", _f: "DD-MM-YYYY", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: {…}, _d: Date Thu Mar 30 1950 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), _isValid: true }
```

upon running the function

```
var diff = licenseDate.diff(birthdate, 'years')
```

it returns NaN

Comment: your code it's working to me: https://jsfiddle.net/u8b69gpf/ so you are doing something wrong beyond what you wrote here

Comment: @DiegoDeVita i am just running it inside onBlur of an Input :)

Comment: maybe you should write that part in your question because the NaN scenario isn't there and isn't clear what you did wrong

Answer (score 1):

`DD-MM-YYYY` is not the correct date format, you should try with `YYYY-MM-DD`, It will work fine

```
let a="1999-03-30"
let b="2022-03-30"
var date1 = moment(a);
var date2 = moment(b);
console.log(date1.diff(date2, 'years'))
```

and It will also with `DD-MM-YYYY`

```
let a="30-03-1999"
let b="30-03-2022"
var date1 = moment(a, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
var date2 = moment(b, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
console.log(date1.diff(date2, 'days'))
```

Comment: it can be correct as well... the format specified is consistent with the dates written in strings. And its code works actually. He just didn't test it correctly